# Почистить строку от лишних пробельных символов

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
"St Petersburg       \r\n      Moscow    \r\n"
```

Её нужно преобразовать в:

```
"St Petersburg|Moscow"
```

Прошу подсказать наиболее красивый и короткий код для этого.
Придумал такое решение:

```
$str = implode("|", array_map("trim", explode("\r", trim($text))))
```

Он очень ужасен, прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: В вашем коде нет ни чего ужасного.

Comment: Хороший код, не комплексуйте :)

Answer (score 1):

Есть же preg_replace:

```
$text = "St Petersburg       \r\n      Moscow    \r\n";
echo trim(preg_replace("/\s+\r+\s+(?!$)/m", "|", $text));
```

Эта функция заменяет все совпадения с шаблоном на строку для замены, которая идёт вторым параметром. Для более подробного изучения функции посмотрите документацию на [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: Я минуснул, потому что Ваш код не работает. Во-первых, Вы пропустили ограничивающий символ вокруг регулярки. Во-вторых, он возвращает ``St Petersburg|Moscow|`` вместо требуемого ``St Petersburg|Moscow``.

Comment: Хмм, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Вообще, по-моему эта задача — хорошая иллюстрация к «Некоторые люди, когда им встречается проблема, говорят «Я знаю, я использую регулярные выражения». Теперь у вас две проблемы». Тут надо либо использовать ``trim``, чтобы удалить лишнюю |, либо две регулярки (тогда чем этот код будет лучше оригинального кода с ``implode``/``explode``?), либо lookback/lookahead expressions (но тогда регулярка станет сложной для понимания, т.е. решение будет хуже оригинального с ``implode``/``explode``). В конечном итоге, по-моему ``preg_replace`` тут не подходит, а оригинальный код хороший.

Comment: Знаете, Оккам Вас не пощадил бы :)

Comment: Буду рад, если Вы мне покажете лучший код, чем у автора. Мне лично придумать его не удалось. Разве что можно заменить ``trim`` на ``array_filter``, но польза сомнительна. Ещё можно использовать ``preg_match_all`` вместо ``implode``+``trim``, но польза тоже сомнительна. Других вариантов не вижу. Если Вы видите — честь Вам и хвала.

Comment: Ну 2 регулярки - это и правда хуже оригинального кода. А сложность для понимания регулярок - это уже дело субъективное)) Хотя оригинальный код и правда не плох.

Comment: Если бы St Peterburg писался бы не через пробел, было бы проще. Тем и хорош вопрос :)

Comment: @ДмитрийКушнарёв кстати я исправил, теперь всё должно работать

Comment: @YuryPlinto У меня до сих пор выдаёт ``St Petersburg|Moscow|`` вместо необходимого ``St Petersburg|Moscow``. Если честно, не уверен, что тут можно обойтись без ``trim``ʼа.

Comment: @labris в St Peterburg 1 пробел, в других местах всегда больше. Но при желании можно и за /r зацепиться: вместо \r* поставить \r+ тогда на пробелы без перевода каретки регулярка не будет обращать внимания

Comment: @ДмитрийКушнарёв , странно. Пошёл потестирую

Comment: nl2br($text) Дает неплохой промежуточный результат, осталось pipe прикрутить, но тут уж сам пока не пойму как :)

Comment: @ДмитрийКушнарёв , выяснил причину. Пробелы перед \r тоже подходили под регулярное выражение с условием >=0 \r. Заменил на >=1. теперь всё работает.

Comment: @YuryPlinto Не работает. Теперь результатом выражения является строка ``"St Petersburg|Moscow    \r\n"``, а по условию нужна ``"Petersburg|Moscow"``.

Comment: @ДмитрийКушнарёв , согласен - тут без trim- а не обойтись. Можно конечно строку перезаписать, используя группы,  но это некрасиво. Да и вряд ли это будет проще trim-а для простого подрезания хвостовых символов.

Answer (score 0):

Сравнил два варианта (автор и @YuryPlinto):

```
<?php
$text0 = "St Petersburg       \r\n      Moscow    \r\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) $text .= $text0;
$t0 = microtime(true);
$str = implode("|", array_map("trim", explode("\r", trim($text))));
$t1 = microtime(true);
$str = preg_replace('/\s*\n\s*(?!$)/', "|", $text);
$t2 = microtime(true);
echo 'explode-implode time: '.($t1-$t0).'<br/>preg_replace time: '.($t2-$t1);
```

Оказалось, что регулярное выражение вдвое быстрее, что не удивительно. Удивительно, что всего вдвое.

```
explode-implode time: 0.32872295379639
preg_replace time: 0.15778708457947
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно заменить `explode` на `preg_split`

```
$text = "St Petersburg       \r\n      Moscow    \r\n";

$str = implode('|', preg_split('/\s*\r\s*/', trim($text)));

var_dump($str); // string(20) "St Petersburg|Moscow"
```